# Аргументы имеют неверный тип, при попытке установить ссылку на значения у adotable

Tags: c++, c++builder

"Написал" клиентское приложения с возможностью работы с хранилищем БД.
Есть пул компонентов:

- ADOTable4 - таблица поликлиника;
- ADOTable3 - таблица клиенты
- ADOTable2 - таблица доктора;
- ADOTable1 - таблица визиты;

К ним прилагаются 4 datasourse. 
И один adoconnection.

Пример: при попытке сделать ссылку с таблицы поликлиника, столбец номер поликлиники в таблицу доктора, столбец номер поликлиники, появляется диалоговое окно:

> Аргументы имеют неверный тип, выходят за пределы допустимого диапазона или вступают в конфликт друг с другом.
>   Более подробно что я делаю:
>   Выбрав компонент adotable4 в свойствах 
>   в mastersourse указываю datasourse2, после нажимаю на masterfields и указываю что с чего на что нужно ссылаться. Ниже представлен код ошибки.

Проект + бд находятся здесь: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Hlg0J46iuJ1jEvTv26puGc3HdtcVp5fN?usp=sharing

Очень нужна помощь, за ранее спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Схема данных.

Код ошибки:

```
  [5185BE7B]{adortl250.bpl} Data.Win.ADODB.TCustomADODataSet.InternalSetSort (Line 6013, "Data.Win.ADODB.pas" + 1) + $13
    [50068EB0]{rtl250.bpl  } System.@CheckAutoResult (Line 38448, "System.pas" + 4) + $6
    [5185BE7B]{adortl250.bpl} Data.Win.ADODB.TCustomADODataSet.InternalSetSort (Line 6013, "Data.Win.ADODB.pas" + 1) + $13
    [5185BEC3]{adortl250.bpl} Data.Win.ADODB.TCustomADODataSet.SetSort (Line 6021, "Data.Win.ADODB.pas" + 3) + $4
    [5185C149]{adortl250.bpl} Data.Win.ADODB.TCustomADODataSet.SetIndexFieldNames (Line 6050, "Data.Win.ADODB.pas" + 10) + $2D
    [22FE67DF]{dclado250.bpl} ADOReg.TADOTableFieldLinkProperty.SetIndexFieldNames (Line 510, "ADOReg.pas" + 0) + $3
    [2301E919]{dcldb250.bpl} FldLinks.TLinkFields.Edit (Line 266, "FldLinks.pas" + 6) + $E
    [2301E6F1]{dcldb250.bpl} FldLinks.EditMasterFields (Line 166, "FldLinks.pas" + 5) + $3
    [5005FBCD]{rtl250.bpl  } System.@AsClass (Line 17433, "System.pas" + 2) + $8
    [2301E829]{dcldb250.bpl} FldLinks.TFieldLinkProperty.Edit (Line 228, "FldLinks.pas" + 1) + $9
    [22FE676E]{dclado250.bpl} ADOReg.TADOTableFieldLinkProperty.Edit (Line 495, "ADOReg.pas" + 2) + $2
    [20992E9F]{coreide250.bpl} PropInsp.TPropertyInspector.PropListEditDblClick (Line 976, "PropInsp.pas" + 20) + $5
    [213E6709]{vclide250.bpl} IDEInspListBox.TInspListBox.DoEditDblClick (Line 626, "IDEInspListBox.pas" + 2) + $A
    [213E7FAE]{vclide250.bpl} IDEInspListBox.TInspListBox.EditDblClick (Line 1203, "IDEInspListBox.pas" + 0) + $2
    [50AC51A1]{vcl250.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TControl.DblClick (Line 7447, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 1) + $14
    [50AC531C]{vcl250.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TControl.WMLButtonDblClk (Line 7490, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 4) + $C
    [50AC4C16]{vcl250.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TControl.WndProc (Line 7326, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 91) + $6
    [50063F40]{rtl250.bpl  } System.@FinalizeArray (Line 32151, "System.pas" + 139) + $0
    [5005FD9F]{rtl250.bpl  } System.TObject.Dispatch (Line 17809, "System.pas" + 11) + $0
    [0CB38A5E]{themeloader250.bpl} Idetheme.Vclstylehooks.TIDEStyleHook.WndProc + $7A
    [50067898]{rtl250.bpl  } System.@IntfClear (Line 37236, "System.pas" + 10) + $0
    [0CB38513]{themeloader250.bpl} Idetheme.Vclstylehooks.TIDEStyleHook.HandleMessage + $B7
    [50AC9009]{vcl250.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.IsControlMouseMsg (Line 9960, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 9) + $2A
    [0CB6F7C6]{themeloader250.bpl} Idetheme.Stylemanager.TIDEThemeStyleEngine.UnRegisterSysStyleHook + $106
    [50AC97FB]{vcl250.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 10197, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 166) + $6
    [213E5E4B]{vclide250.bpl} IDEInspListBox.TPropInspEdit.WndProc (Line 363, "IDEInspListBox.pas" + 7) + $4
    [50AC8DC8]{vcl250.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.MainWndProc (Line 9896, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 3) + $6
    [5016EBC4]{rtl250.bpl  } System.Classes.StdWndProc (Line 17406, "System.Classes.pas" + 9) + $2
    [50C11A6F]{vcl250.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.ProcessMessage (Line 10613, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 23) + $1
    [50C11AB2]{vcl250.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.HandleMessage (Line 10643, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 1) + $4
    [50C11DE5]{vcl250.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.Run (Line 10781, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 26) + $3
    [005088E2]{bds.exe     } bds.bds (Line 212, "" + 7) + $7
```

Comment: Вряд ли кто-то станет скачивать и смотреть архив с кодом, чтобы вам помочь? Можете добавить в вопрос [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка исправляется путем написания названия таблиц и столбцов на английском языке